# Probability and choices of events in a finite sample space

Tags: probability

I am doing [this Probability MOOC](https://www.edx.org/course/probability-basic-concepts-discrete-random-variables-0) from edX. I can't understand concept of number of events. [image]

How come D,E and F are events. They don't make any sense.  I mean, practically, if I have to choose one item from a set of 3 items. I will just choose one. So I get 3 choices.  Why remove 1 item and then group others into 2 and choose one and make it an event ?

Comment: This was useful in learning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(probability_theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are conflating the definition of an *event* with the definition of an *outcome*. You are correct that there are only three outcomes in this sample space. 
However, an event is a set of [possibly multiple] outcomes. The solution enumerates all possible sets of the three outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I will be happy if I a dot or a star. What is the probability that I will be happy?

That would corresponds to event $D$.

It doesn't mean we pick both items, we will be happy if at least one of them is chosen.

An event is a set of outcomes of an experiment (a subset of the sample space) to which a probability is assigned